# No "usedata()" function in R

Tags: r

There is a command below in [this blog](https://advstats.psychstat.org/book/mregression/importance.php):

```
usedata('gpa')
```

When I run this code, an error occur:

```
Error: could not find function "usedata"
```

I searched and could not find this `usedata()` function.
In addition, I tried `data("gpa")`, but still cannot load this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that it is a custom made function which reads a csv file.
[Here](https://advstats.psychstat.org/book/mregression/index.php) the authors write that:

> In this example, we use a set of simulated data (generated by us). The
>   data are saved in the file gpa.csv.